# align divs inside a table cell once left one centered

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something that should be fairly simple.  I have a column of text in a table that has values from 1 to 18.  I want the cell that has the text to align center.  However, sometimes, the same cell needs to display an asterisk (*).  When the asterisk is displayed, it should be aligned left in the same cell, while keeping the numbers themselves perfectly aligned.

I can't quite get it to align the right way

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center" width=50>
      <div>
        <div style="float:left;">*</div>
        <div>14</div>
      </div>  
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align=center>
      <div></div>
      <div>16</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why can't you move asterisk to separate `td`?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Because then there would be a whole other column which is bordered.

Comment: @Don you can remove borders for this `td` and apply borders for all other `td`s using CSS.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Then the numbers won't be centered in the table still. They will be shifted down the line. And yes you could keep hacking ways to get it to work, but that would be counter productive.

Comment: The reason I don't want an extra cell is because it will take up space even when it's not needed.  The asterisk is only there sometimes.  There is room to fit it in the same cell, I just can't quite figure out the parent child alignment part

Answer (score 7):

Just give `position: absolute` to the `div` with asterisk, and your numbers will be always centered properly:

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center" width=50>
      <div>
        <div style="position: absolute;">*</div>
        <div>14</div>
      </div>  
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align=center>
      <div></div>
      <div>16</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this case `position: absolute` tells: "Don't consider absolutely positioned `div`'s dimensions". If you will inspect the `div` with number, you will see, that it takes the full width and height of parent element, like the `div` with asterisk is not in DOM.

May be my explanation is a little poor and not 100% correctly, but it should give you the basic understanding. For more info look through "position: absolute" area in this site or somewhere else: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: @commercial_suicide, that's awesome.  One more complication.  If I also want to do that to some text on the right on the number like add CP sometimes, I can't quite get it to do the same.  I tried doing position absolute and right:0 on another div, but it puts it outside of the table. https://jsfiddle.net/pixelwiz/h5qz0njo/1/

Comment: @pixelwiz, you need to set `position: relative` for parent `div` and absolutely positioned child will be positioned relatively to the parent. Here is the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h5qz0njo/2/